# What's the best way to do IPv6 check in PHP?

Tags: php, ip, ipv6

Right now I'm using strcmp but that's not really optimal.

So, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [filter_var](https://www.php.net/filter_var) :

```
if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6)) {
    echo "IPV6 valid.";
} else {
    echo "Not valid.";
}
```

You can find the list of filters [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

Comment: Probably the best solution. I didnt know that a Filter for IPv6 exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use strcmp instead of strcpy. That must be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check, if a `:` is in the ip-adress:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],":") !== false) //....IPv6
else //....IPv4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [inet_pton](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php). Also works for ipv4:

```
function ip_validate($ip){
    return inet_pton($ip) !== false;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but as far as i know, he wants to know if its IPv6 OR IPv4. This will return true, no matter if its IPv6 or IPv4

Comment: Really? Couldn't deduct that from the question.

Comment: Well, he asks `What's the best way to do IPv6 check in PHP?`. If he just wants to check for an IP, he wouldnt have asked for IPv6. But idk, maybe i just misunderstood him.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` this is your buddy. It checks for the adress. I suppose the simplest way would be to check this address for a non-numeric sign. If it contains one, its a IPv6 address. Maybe there are better or more elegant ones, but ive never used it because no provider is using IPv6 yet.